# How to center Mapbox camera to a given feature?

Tags: swift, mapbox

I'm  rendering some FillLayers starting from a geoJSON features list.

Now I would like to programmatically move the camera to center to a given feature so that the whole feature is visible in the viewport.

```
    func centerCameraTo(feature: Feature) {
        guard let mapView = self.mapView else { print("[centerCameraTo] no mapView"); return }
        
        mapView.mapboxMap.setCamera(to: ???)

    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for MultiPolygon:

```
    func fitCameraToPolygonFeatures(features: [Feature]) {
        guard let mapView = self.mapView else { print("[fitCameraToPolygonFeatures] no mapView"); return }
        
        var coordinateBounds: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        
        for feature in features {
            if case let .multiPolygon(multiPolygon) = feature.geometry {
                if let bounds = calculateBoundingBox(coordinates: multiPolygon.coordinates) {
                    let featureCoordinateBounds = [
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bounds.minLatitude, longitude: bounds.minLongitude),
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bounds.maxLatitude, longitude: bounds.maxLongitude)
                    ]
                    coordinateBounds.append(contentsOf: featureCoordinateBounds)
                }
            } else {
                print("[fitCameraToPolygonFeatures] cannot cast to Polygon for feature: \(feature)")
            }
        }
        
        if !coordinateBounds.isEmpty {
            let cameraOptions = mapView.mapboxMap.camera(
                for: coordinateBounds,
                padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2, right: 20),
                bearing: mapView.mapboxMap.cameraState.bearing,
                pitch: 0
            )
            mapView.camera.fly(to: cameraOptions, duration: 0.3, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

`calculateBoundingBox` is:

```
func calculateBoundingBox(coordinates: [[[LocationCoordinate2D]]]) -> (minLatitude: Double, maxLatitude: Double, minLongitude: Double, maxLongitude: Double)? {
    guard let firstCoordinate = coordinates.first?.first?.first else {
        return nil
    }
    
    var minLatitude = firstCoordinate.latitude
    var maxLatitude = firstCoordinate.latitude
    var minLongitude = firstCoordinate.longitude
    var maxLongitude = firstCoordinate.longitude
    
    for polygon in coordinates {
        for ring in polygon {
            for coordinate in ring {
                if coordinate.latitude < minLatitude {
                    minLatitude = coordinate.latitude
                }
                if coordinate.latitude > maxLatitude {
                    maxLatitude = coordinate.latitude
                }
                if coordinate.longitude < minLongitude {
                    minLongitude = coordinate.longitude
                }
                if coordinate.longitude > maxLongitude {
                    maxLongitude = coordinate.longitude
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return (minLatitude, maxLatitude, minLongitude, maxLongitude)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the type of your feature, if it is a Point, you can extract the coordinates and use [setCenter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setcenter)

```
function centerCameraTo(feature: Featuere<Point>) {
   mapView.setCenter(feature.geometry.coordinates);
}
```

if the geometry is more complex (polygon, LineString etc.), you can use the [fitBounds](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#fitbounds) function.

Comment: It's a polygon. Sorry about that! Do you have any examples?

Comment: I guess my problem is that feature.geometry.coordinates tells me there's no coordinates on geometry. -- I can't specialyze feature: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Feature'

Comment: Can you provide working code example (codepen, codesandbox for example)?